# Getting image width and height from PNG without library

Tags: regex, image, perl, png

Based on specification of PNG (Portable Network Graphics) file, a very **[first chunk](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html)** has to be `IHDR` (4 bytes),  contains the image's width, height, and bit depth. So right behind `IHDR` are 4 bytes representing `width` and then next 4 bytes representing `height` of the image.

Is it safe to use regex `/IHDR(.{4})(.{4})/s` and convert `$1` and `$2` into `width` and `height`? If so, how can I do such conversion? Should I use `unpack("N", $x)` or `unpack("V", $x)` ..?

---

My current code (*not sure if it works for large images*):

```
if ($png =~ m/^\x89PNG\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A....IHDR(.{4})(.{4})/s) {
  ($width, $height) = (unpack("N", $1) , unpack("N", $2));  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just looked up the png specification; there's more stuff in front of the IHDR. So this should work:

```
open(IN, "<xx.png");
binmode(IN);
read(IN, $header, 24);
if (substr($header, 12, 4) ne "IHDR") {
    die "this is not a PNG file";
}
($width, $height)=unpack("NN", substr($header, 16));
print "width: $width height: $height\n";
close IN;
```

Comment: When dealing with binary data, like in this case, i generally prefer substr() to regexes, because i don't have to care about special characters like '\n' that suggest end of line to the regex.

Comment: Yes, there is 8-byte PNG header and 4 bytes representing size of IHDR chunk, followed by IHDR (4 bytes/characters), width (4 bytes), height (4 bytes), ...

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer from 7 years later...

If you're processing the png at the binary level, the width is specified by the 17-20 bytes inclusive (17, 18, 19, 20) and the height is specified by the 21-24 bytes inclusive (21, 22, 23, 24).